# Upload video with php and html

Tags: php, html

How can i upload a video ? i did this with a image file but is not working with a video one only showing "error"

```
    <?php 
 session_start();

 if( !isset($_SESSION["username"]) ){




         echo "<p id='errors'>Por favor, loguese, si no es redireccionado haga click <a href='log.php'>aqui</a></p>";
 header("location: log.php");


 }else{
 };
$img = $_GET["fileToUploadv"];

$target_dir = "video/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUploadv"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUploadv"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "The file is not an image!.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists

// Check file size

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "mp4" && $imageFileType != "mp4" ) {
    echo "Only use a .JPG file.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
if (file_exists($target_file)) {

    unlink("video/video.mp4");
    unlink("video/video.avi");

}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Error.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUploadv"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {





        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUploadv"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        rename("video/".basename( $_FILES["fileToUploadv"]["name"]), "video/video.mp4");
        rename("video/".basename( $_FILES["fileToUploadv"]["name"]), "video/video.avi");

    } else {
        echo "Error.";
    }
}
?>
```

this script have filetouploadv that is with a form input to upload mp4 or avi that is html

```
<form id="formimg" method="post" action="uploadvideo.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 

    <label for="uploadimgg">
        <p id="selectimg">Please select a MP4 or AVI file to upload.</p>
        <i class="fas fa-upload"></i>
    </label>
    <input id="uploadimgg" type="file" name="fileToUploadv" accept="video/mp4,video/avi">

  <input class="hideshowsub"  id="submitpho" type="submit">
</form>
```

should change the name to video and upload to video/ but is not working ...move_uploaded_file because that reutrn false and do the "error" message

Comment: you could generate the edit fields with the table and toggle their visibility with the button... that way you don't have to do the looping...

Comment: You could add a hidden element with the number or better add to the id of an element in the row...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
   require("config.php");

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM inventario";
   $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
   echo("<table>");
   echo("<tr>");
   echo ("<th class='midtable'>"."Username"."</th>");
   echo ("<th class='midtable'>"."Password"."</th>");
   echo ("<th class='midtable'>"."</th>");
   echo ( "</tr>");

   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
        {
          echo("<tr>");
          echo("<td><div class='data'>".$row['username']."</div><div class='edit'><input type='text' name='usrname' value='".$row['username']."'></div></td>"."<td><div class='data'".$row['password']."<div class='edit'><input type='text' name='password' value='".$row['password']."'></div></td>"."<td>"."<i class='fas fa-edit'></i>"."<i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i>"."</td>"  );
          echo("</tr>") ;
         }; ?>
```

and then using jQuery hide the class data and show the class edit elements in the row and a submit button to update the values in the DB... and perhaps update just that row...

Answer (score 0):

You can't upload videos because of this:

```
if($check !== false)
```

Turn it from `false` to `true`:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUploadv"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== true) {
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "The file is not an image!.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
```